# Unable to retrieve metadata for 'MVCMusicStore.Models.Album

Tags: asp.net-mvc

In section 5 of the ASP>NET MVC Music Store example, "Creating the StoreManagerController," when I click "Add" I get the error,

> There was an error running the selected code generator:
>   'Unable to retrieve metadata for 'MVCMusicStore.Models.Album.'

The popular solution is to comment out the connection string in Web.config. This did not work for me. After trying many things I decided to add the code manually, by taking it from the completed code that's included with the example. When I do that I receive the error,

> Compiler Error Message: CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Album' does not exist in the namespace 'MvcMusicStore.Models' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

and on line 31 I see the error,

> public class _Page_Views_StoreManager_Index_cshtml : System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage<IEnumerable<MvcMusicStore.Models.Album>>

Album is defined in the models folder. I have used webform development many times and am trying to add MVC to my repertoire. It seems to me "Album' is not registered, but I don't even know if that's appropriate lingo for MVC. What's the problem? I'm running this example in Visual Studio 2017.

Comment: It occurred to me that the app lets you browse albums by genre, and click on a album to see details. This works. How can the app know what albums is in one place but not another? In the edit portion shown above it doesn't know what album is.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with line 31 is my project is named "MVCMusicStore". In the completed code I imported it's "MvcMusicStore". So it's looking at the wrong thing for the 'Album'namespace. Still don't know what causes the first error.

After correcting the namespace in the sample file, that error goes away and the new error is on the line;

```
 @foreach (var item in Model{

 the error is "System.NullReferenceException 'Object reference not set to   an instance of an object.'
```